# Hyperlink HTML page

Tags: c#, asp.net, hyperlink

I am using an asp page where I want to have a hyperlink that, if clicked, will load an html page in the browser.\but as i user the asp:hyperlink and I am also giving the path of the html page where the page is stored.  However, when clicked, it is not loading that html page..
i am using the hyperlink as:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="hlinkTest" runat="server">Preview</asp:HyperLink>
```

and i am giving the url as

```
 hlinkTest.NavigateUrl = "file:///E:/user/aspnet_app/source/test.html";
```

what can be the better solution for getting html page in browser..

Comment: Where are you providing the Navigate URL in the code behind...

Comment: i am giving the navigate url on c# page..

Comment: Where in the Page... Inside Page Load event or in which event exatcly. use hlinkTest.NavigateUrl = @"file://E:/user/aspnet_app/source/test.html";      Make sure the page exits... copy this URL to the browser address bar and enter. You should see a page...

Comment: when i enter the url on page it is showing the page but using hyperlink it is not showing..

Comment: I've no idea why it's not... Perhaps you should try it with different browser or what... can you post the code and aspx of your page

Answer (score 1):

I would be concerned that by trying to access a specific file location, you're opening yourself up for problems. You might have some real trouble porting the site to a new location.

If the target file is in the same folder as your hyperling source you could use:

hlinkText.NavigateUrl = "~/test.html";

Good luck.

Comment: it is showing an error "Firefox doesn't know how to open this address, because the protocol (e) isn't associated with any program."

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<a href="file:///E:/user/aspnet_app/source/test.html">Preview</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget that the client browser will be unable to load a `file:` url unless a file with that name and path exists and the user has read access to it. So in the OP's original example, unless the machine running the browser that's trying to load `file:///E:/user/aspnet_app/source/test.html` has a readable file at `E:\user\aspnet_app\source\test.html`, they're get a big fat error along the lines of `file or directory does not exist or can't be found`. Try giving the user an `http:` URL, absolute (`http://www.mysite.org/foo/bar/baz.html`) or relative (`foo/bar/baz.html`). If relative, the path will be taken relative to the URL of the current page.